# Video/audio playback control Chrome extension with settings per URL regex

Tags: gratis, video, audio, chrome, browser-extension

I'm often listening to sped up videos and looking for an extension that specifically can:

- set playback speed of videos (and optionally audio) on different websites, supporting as many players as possible, including ones that don't have buttons to set the speed
- remember playback speed for various website - e.g. whole site with movies - `1.5`, specific YouTube channel - `1.75`, different YouTube channel - `1.25`
- *optionally* control the speed with some keyboard shortcuts
- export and later import its settings. Or even better save them to Google account with help of Chrome API.

It should be free.

Does anyone use anything like that? I noticed a bunch of extensions that do one thing, but not others, I might end up using 2-3 of them, but I'd prefer 1 if there's any that covers everything.